# Unmanaged package is taking too long time to install

Tags: unmanaged-package, package-install

I have a un-managed  SFDC package which I want to install on a highly customized SFDC org ,this org already has 5 other packages installed.

None of the package components is overlapping with existing components.

When i tried to install this package , SFDC showed a message saying Email will be sent on successful installation.

But its been more than 36 hours , and no email has been received.

Nor can i see the package in the installed packages list.

Is there a upper-bound on maximum  time required to install the package?

Comment: check  Custom Apps ,Custom Tabs and any limits exceed in sandbox

Comment: Do you have any post install handlers in your package? I've had some situations where post install script would break silently and the package  installation never completed.

Comment: Have you checked the "Installed Packages"? It may be that the email got lost, but the package was still installed.