# Managed package takes too long to install

Tags: app, postinstall, beta-managed-package, package-install

When developing a huge app (200+ classes, because FFlib and separation of conserns), Salesforce throws me an error while installing the package in a test environment:

[image]

The install proceeds after a few minutes, and the package is installed. Since I can't debug the code in the test environment, I do not know what might be causing this delay. I know Salesforce executes the tests while generating the package and while installing it, might this be the cause?

Has anyone had an issue like this? I already looked a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47682/unmanaged-package-is-taking-too-long-time-to-install) in here, but the case is a little different than mine (his install took more than a day, while mine takes a few more minutes).

Comment: In my experience, most managed package installations do this - nothing to worry about.

Comment: Agree with Phil; it is not an error it is normal - 5 yo 15 minutes - for anything but small managed packages.

Comment: But what if I want to show a custom visualforce as a post-install instructions page? Clicking on "Done" redirects the user to the installed packages page, and to access my custom page the user would have to click in the package's name in the list of installed packages, and then click on "[View]" in the page with the package information. This is awful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could send an email to the person who installed the package with the url of the visualforce with your instructions.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=apex_post_install_script_create.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Since it seems that it is a limitation of the platform, I believe this would be, indeed, the way to do this. I can only hope that Salesforce let us customize the timeout value in the future, or simply redirect the user automatically while he is browsing his organization, or something like that.